# How to delete consumers of a stream in Redis?

Tags: redis

I'm able to delete a Redis stream using 'del' command in Redis. I guess this will also delete the Consumer Groups/Consumers for that stream. However, I want to delete Consumers explicitly. Does Redis allow that ? If not, how to manage consumers which aren't in use anymore ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Found the answer in docs, XGROUP allows deleting consumers in that group using DELCONSUMER:

> XGROUP [CREATE key groupname id-or-$] [SETID key groupname id-or-$] [DESTROY key groupname] [DELCONSUMER key groupname consumername]

Comment: What happens with the pending ones?